# How to display images from storage path using artisan serve

Tags: laravel

I was using laravel by the project URL without using `serve` and i didn't have this kind of problems.

But now i'm using it, so i thought that this is the reason.

I've got a problem to display the images from storage path, i tried some stuff like run the storage link `PHP artisan storage:link` and get the path using `storage_path('app/' . $filename)` but it didn't work

Comment: It works `img src="{{ url('storage/app/'.$filename) }}"` in view

Comment: Thank you, it works with me for the first time, i appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not providing correct path to the storage_path helper  your `storage_path('app/' . $filename)` is not working because you have not put `/` before `app` try putting a slash before `app` like `storage_path('/app/' . $filename)`

also

if you want to get the file in blade then you can use `url` helper like `{{ url('storage/app/'.$filename) }}`